# Yii: render process

Tags: performance, yii, render

I would like to know if someone could explain me what happens exactly when we call a "render".

Let me introduce you my problem:

**This is my action:**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $new_user = new CustomUser;
    $new_person = new CustomPerson;

    $tab_person = $this->getListPerson();
    $this->render('index',array('tab'=>$tab_person,
                                'user'=>$new_user,
                                'person'=>$new_person));
}
```

**And this is my index view:**

```
.
. 
.
</p> <br/>   
<?php $this->renderPartial('person-form', array('person'=>$person,
                                                'user' =>$user ));
?>
```

So my problem is that the loading page time is very long. 
If I put a

> die("die");

just befor the render in my actionIndex or at the end of my view (after the renderPartial) the execution is very fast. I'll see "die"(and my index page if I put the statement at the end of it) after 0.3 second. But if I put it after my render or I don't put it, then my page is going to be loaded correctly but in 4-5 secondes.

So I think I didn't understand very well what happens after a render. I repeat if I stop the execution at the end of my view page it's very fast, but at the end of my action it's very slow. I thought about js and css, but after looking into I didn't see anything and Firebug shows me that these files are loaded very quickly.
And if I put the "die()" statment at the end of my layout main.php it's very fast as well.

[image]

So I know that render will show the page and wrap it in the layout but is there another thing which maybe could make the action very slow?

If anybody has an idea about my problem I would be very grateful.

Sorry if I did mistakes, English is not my mothertongue.

Thank you for reading me, have a good day :)

Michaël

Comment: See http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/ . Step through the code with a debugger to see what's going on, use a profiler to see which parts are taking the most time.

Comment: For the quick answer to your question, look at the arrow diagram at the bottom of DCoder's link. In essence, your content is built inside out (basic view and renderPartials, then layout, then CSS/JS

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it should not load slower. Maybe you have something else loaded on the page.
Try enabling the logs on the screen: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/58/sql-logging-and-profiling-in-firebug-yii-1-1/ . See if there is anything executed after the view is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

One reason that this may look confusing, is that it may not be the "rendering" that is slow. It may be that loading models and relations are slow, but by default they are lazy loaded. This means the DB won't be queried until the code that asks for them is hit, which is often in the view.

This might explain why the rendering is slow. So like others said, you need to enable logging, either in the page or log to firebug. You can then check for any slow queries or components.